# ruby gem 'gmaps4rails' can be used for a ruby sinantra application

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, gmaps4rails

I want to make a simple geofencing app for google maps just using ruby.  Is it possible that you can use this gem without rails and are there any  examples out there showing this?

Thanks,
A.J.

Comment: yes, just take the js if you wish, create the json yourself but its quite easy

Comment: FYI, here its even used outside of Rails: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q6hp5LrqYHa1xc7AYhJh?p=preview